# jquery not loading after ajax page transition callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the fasw non jquery page transition plugin. The Ajax part works when I click on a link, but whenever I return to the page, the jquery doesn't load. What should I do?

Thank you in adavnce.

http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/

```
 <pre>
            function ft(params){
            var ol=document.addEventListener?"DOMContentLoaded":"load";
            var navB=params.navB||"";
            var but=params.but||false;
            var cBa=params.cBa||
            function(){};
            function aDL(url,t,o){
              if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                  r=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
               else if(window.ActiveXObject)
                  {
                    r=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
               }if(r!=undefined){
                  r.onreadystatechange=function(){
                      Ol(r,t,o);
                  };
                  r.open("GET",url,true);
                  r.send("");
              }
          }

           function Ol(r,t,o){
              if(r.readyState==4){
                  if(r.status==200||r.status==0){
                      t.innerHTML=r.responseText;
                      o();
                  }else{
                      t.innerHTML="Error:\n"+r.status+"\n"+r.statusText;
                  }
               }
           }
           function DE(){
              var dochtml=document.body.innerHTML;
              document.body.innerHTML="";
              var d1=document.createElement("div");d1.id="d1";
              d1.style.zIndex=2;d1.style.position="absolute";
              d1.style.width="100%";d1.style.height="100%";
              d1.style.left="0px";d1.style.top="0px";
              document.body.appendChild(d1);d1.innerHTML=dochtml;
              var d2=document.createElement("div");d2.id="d2";
              d2.style.zIndex=1;d2.style.position="absolute";
              d2.style.width="100%";d2.style.height="100%";
              d2.style.left="0px";d2.style.top="0px";
              document.body.appendChild(d2);
              return{d1:d1,d2:d2}
          }
           function timeOuts(e,d1,d2){
               setTimeout(function(){
                  d1.className=e+" out"},1);
               setTimeout(function(){
                  d2.className=e+" in"},1);
               setTimeout(function(){
                  document.body.innerHTML=d2.innerHTML;cBa()
              },706);
          }
           function slideTo(href,effect,pushstate){
              var d=DE();
              var d1=d.d1;
              var d2=d.d2;
              aDL(href,d2,function(){
                  if(pushstate&&window.history.pushState)
                      window.history.pushState("","",href);
                  timeOuts(effect,d1,d2);
              });
          }
           function dC(e){
              var o;
              var o=e.srcElement||e.target;var tn=o.tagName.toLowerCase();
               if(!but||tn!="input"||o.getAttribute("type")!="button") {
                  while(tn!=="a"&&tn!=="body"){
                      o=o.parentNode;tn=o.tagName.toLowerCase();
                  }
                  if(tn==="body")
                      return;
              }
              var t=o.getAttribute("data-ftrans");
              if(t){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var hr=o.getAttribute("href")||o.getAttribute("data-href");
                  if(hr)slideTo(hr,t,true)
              }
          }
            function aE(ev,el,f){
               if(el.addEventListener)el.addEventListener(ev,f,false);
              else if(el.attachEvent){
                  var r=el.attachEvent("on"+ev,f);
                  return r;
               }
           }

              aE("click",window,dC);
              aE(ol,document,function(ev){
              aE("popstate",window,function(e){
                slideTo(location.pathname,navB,false);
               });
           });
        }



        $(document).ready(function() {
               $('.title').click(function(){
               $('.sub_title').slideToggle(300).addClass('.sub_title_show');
               });

           function close_menu(){
               $('.sub_title').slideUp(300);
            }


    <code>
```

Comment: A [fiddle](https://Jsfiddle.net) would be nice.